# Syntax error when inserting into foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I keep getting errors trying to insert data into my table. I have tried:

```
insert into saferdb_dot_contacts (fax, email, "dot_num_id") 
values( 'nan', 'nan', 4);
```

> ERROR: column "dot_num_id" of relation "saferdb_dot_contacts" >does
>   not exist

I tried:

```
insert into saferdb_dot_contacts (fax, email, dot_num_id) 
values( 'nan', 'nan', 4);
```

> ERROR: column "dot_num_id" of relation "saferdb_dot_contacts" >does
>   not exist

I tried to access the field via

```
SELECT dot_num_id FROM saferdb_dot_contacts;
```

but got :

> ERROR: column "dot_num_id" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT dot_num_id FROM >saferdb_dot_contacts;

I tried:

```
SELECT 'dot_num_id' FROM saferdb_dot_contacts;
```

Which gave me a strange output of a column labled ?column?

[image]

if it helps dot_num_id is has a foreign key relationship to another table.

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
SELECT "dot_num_id" FROM saferdb_dot_contacts;
```

> ERROR:  column "dot_num_id" does not exist
>   LINE 2: SELECT "dot_num_id" FROM saferdb_dot_contacts;
>                 ^
>   SQL state: 42703

[image]Character: 58

Comment: Could it be that - as postgres claims - `dot_num_id` doesn't exist on `saferdb_dot_contacts`?  What is the schema of `saferdb_dot_contacts`?

Comment: BTW, in the last query you are trying to select the constant string 'dot_num_id' from the table, hence the output.

Comment: could u please try and see the result for: SELECT "dot_num_id" FROM saferdb_dot_contacts;

Comment: Also, what happens when you try: insert into saferdb_dot_contacts (fax, email, 'dot_num_id') , with single quotes instead of double?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli I just added a screen shot which includes the image of the colums in postgres. I included your sql in question.

Comment: oooh I see, it is DOT_Num_id. Please try: Select "DOT_Num_id" from saferdb_dot_contacts and let me know.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli It works now, but I swear to god I tried that before!!! Thank you! It now works with insert as well!!!

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to watch out for case sensivity and use double quotes. Try:

```
insert into saferdb_dot_contacts (fax, email, "DOT_Num_id") 
values( 'nan', 'nan', 4);
```